# How to create a function that randomly selects a string?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function that adds the string "add" to the list every 5 seconds. How can I make a function so that it randomly selects one of 3 rows and adds it? And every 5 seconds chose another.
Strings: 'add', 'delete', 'remove'.
My code:

```dart
    class EventNotifier extends ValueNotifier<List<String>> {
      EventNotifier(List<String> value) : super(value);
      final stream = Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5));
      late final streamSub = stream.listen((event) {
        value.add('add');
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random is indeed the way to go. Since this is Dart, and not JS, `Math.random()` specifically won't work, but you can use `Random` in `dart:math` instead ;)

```dart
final List<String> options = ["add", "delete", "remove"];

...

value.add(options[Random().nextInt(4)]); // max of 4 to get a random index in [0, 1, 2]
```

Same as the other answer, it's pseudo-random, but definitely good enough